# help with Watir for automated testing a webapp

Tags: watir

I m using Watir for automated testing a webapp.

In one of the page i have something like htis

```
</STYLE></HEAD><BODY background="IMAGES/fon06.gif"><DIV class="mainalignment" height="110%" width="110%"><TABLE class="mainframe" height="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0"><TBODY><TR><TD><DIV id="divTabButtons"><P align="left"> <INPUT class="tabOff" id="1" onclick="tabOnClick(1)" type="button" value="TIMESHEET" /> </P></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

But m able to identify the HTML element to access it.
I need to access the id="1" value="TIMESHEET" element.

How do I do it in Watir.

If more info is required pls let me know.
Note: I am a HTML noob.

EDIT: I tried showAllObjects to see whether the objects are displayed or not.

and this is what I got
-----------Objects in page -------------
HTML Document     name=header         id=                 src=header.jsp
HTML Document     name=body           id=                 src=body.jsp

This is very strange.
but When i look at the page..there are many objects..

I m confused now..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to click the button, any of these will work:

```
browser.button(:id, "1").click
browser.button(:value, "TIMESHEET").click
browser.button(:id => "1", :value => "TIMESHEET").click
```

More information at http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Buttons and http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Multiple+Attributes

Comment: Note that the last example Zeljko gives above should in theory never be needed because according to the HTML specifications, 'ID' attributes are supposed to be unique within a page.  Thus there should never on the same page be two objects with an id of '1'.  If you find that to be the case, I'd recommend a bug be filed that the page is violating HTML spec for ID attribute uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check first, you can do this:

```
if browser.button(:id, "1").exists?
   browser.button(:id, "1").click
```